# Preprocessor: Meaning of "The definition also permits you to split an identifier at any position and get exactly two tokens"

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, token, language-lawyer, identifier

It seems to be generally-understood that there's no way to split a [GNU CPP] preprocessor token into two tokens, but I've found this bit in the GNU CPP manual, and can't seem to figure it out, nor to find any more information about it.

What does this mean?
Section 1.3 Tokenization:

> "A preprocessing number has a rather bizarre definition. The category
>   includes all the normal integer and floating point constants one
>   expects of C, but also a number of other things one might not
>   initially recognize as a number. Formally, preprocessing numbers begin
>   with an optional period, a required decimal digit, and then continue
>   with any sequence of letters, digits, underscores, periods, and
>   exponents. Exponents are the two-character sequences ‘e+’, ‘e-’, ‘E+’,
>   ‘E-’, ‘p+’, ‘p-’, ‘P+’, and ‘P-’. (The exponents that begin with ‘p’
>   or ‘P’ are new to C99. They are used for hexadecimal floating-point
>   constants.)
>
> The purpose of this unusual definition is to isolate the preprocessor
>   from the full complexity of numeric constants. It does not have to
>   distinguish between lexically valid and invalid floating-point
>   numbers, which is complicated. **The definition also permits you to
>   split an identifier at any position and get exactly two tokens, which
>   can then be pasted back together with the ‘##’ operator.** "

--https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html#Tokenization

I am somewhat familiar with using ## to concatenate two tokens; I understand creating, e.g. 'var_1' by using essentially 'var_ ## 1'; what I don't get is why on earth the 'bizarre definition' of 'preprocessing numbers' has anything to do with splitting identifiers and pasting.

Frankly, the first ten times I read that line, I thought for sure it was suggesting there's a bizarre factor of treating a token like a number that would allow it to be split "at any position."

Comment: Interesting catch in the documentation.  I'm fairly sure you do _not_ want to be using whatever loophole it is that allows you to do that.  It will cause confusion at best to those attempting to read your code later; it may not work with other compilers or preprocessors.

Comment: The point is that you can build an identifier `a1b2` by gluing together `a` and `1b2`. `1b2` is a valid preprocessing number, even though it doesn't look much like a number. The sentence you highlight can be more formally stated this way: every prefix and suffix of a valid identifier is a valid preprocessing token; this property is helpful for certain uses of the preprocessor.

Comment: after 15 minutes of thinking the only sensate thing I concluded is that by concatenating a period or a decimal digit with a macro we turn the macro into a number. Maybe stringification of that number may introduce ternary symbols??? don't seems so.. I surrender :D

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

> The definition also permits you to split an identifier at any position and get exactly two tokens, which can then be pasted back together with the `##` operator.

This sentence might be clearer if stated more formally: every prefix and suffix of a valid identifier is a valid preprocessing token. This property is helpful for certain uses of the preprocessor.

For example, you can build an identifier `a1b2` by gluing together `a` and `1b2`. `1b2` is a valid *preprocessing number* (as defined by **[lex.ppnumber]** section of the standard), even though it doesn't look much like a number.

Comment: Of course, take care that you don't stick it too close to the following token. `a0.m` is a valid way of accessing the `m` member of `a0`, where `a0` is an identifier. Splitting that as `a ## 0.m` doesn't work, because then `0.m` is interpreted as a single token. Splitting that as `a ## 0 .m` does work.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped in the same section of the cpp manual and the word I didn't get was that **"split"**. It turns out that throughout the
manual, **"split"** is used as in "separate", or "break into pieces".

So, beginning with the standard definition of a pp-number:

```
pp-number:
    digit
    . digit
    pp-number digit
    pp-number identifier-nondigit
    pp-number exponents
    pp-number .
```

you have to have a **digit** to begin with, or a **.digit**.
So starting with **.5**, you can add anything else after it, it will still be a pp-number.

Now, the "split". Say you have this pp-number, **.5abcd_z0123**
You can split it as **.5abcd_** and **z0123**, but still be able to
concatenate these.

When *not* talking about pp-numbers, *two tokens that don't together form a **valid token** cannot be pasted together.*

So how I view it is that you can break a pp-number anywhere you want it and
have no restriction when you use ## on the resulting parts.

Comment: _"It turns out that throughout the manual, 'split' is used as in 'separate', or 'break into pieces'."_ What else would it mean?

Comment: It's about how you do split it, either manually or programatically. For example, in python docs( splitlines, or splitting a string at a separator), "split" is used as if it's done programatically, _at a certain position_ , (either newline, or a character of choice)

Comment: That sounds like "separating" or "breaking into pieces", to me.